# How to force OS X to always use my VPN?

Tags: macos, vpn

I use the VPN client [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net) to redirect all the traffic to my VPN. However, if Tunnelblick is down, or while it's connecting to my VPN at startup, my trafic is not redirected to my VPN.

This is not an acceptable solution to me, and I would like to know how I can ensure that either my traffic is redirected to my VPN, or I can't connect to the internet.

Useful information:

- I am using Tunnelblick 3.6.3;
- My computer is running OS X 10.11.5, El Capitan;
- I control the server, and am using [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net), but I can accept to change to another software to solve my problem.

Comment: Related: [Prevent outgoing traffic unless OpenVPN connection is active using pf.conf on Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/q/468919/493903)

Comment: Related:  [How can one restrict network activity to only the VPN on a Mac and prevent unsecured internet activity?](http://superuser.com/q/225998/493903)

Comment: These solutions are unfortunately outdated.

Comment: Why do you think that instructions for configuring the pf firewall are outdated?

Comment: Are you looking for a [killswitch](http://www.best-bittorrent-vpn.com/vpn-kill-switch.html)?